# Obtaining a exclusive lock when writing to an HDF5 file

Tags: python

I have the following code which tries to append a pandas dataframe to an HDF5 store. I try to obtain an exclusive file lock so that multiple process/threads/jobs do not write to the HDF5 file at once:

```
 #--------------------------------------------- MODULE IMPORT ----------------------------------------------------------#
    import os
    import time
    from pandas import HDFStore

 #--------------------------------------------- DEVELOPMENT CODE -------------------------------------------------------#
    class SafeHDF5Store(HDFStore):
        """Implement safe HDFStore by obtaining file lock. Multiple writes will queue if lock is not obtained."""

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """Initialize and obtain file lock."""

            interval   = kwargs.pop('probe_interval', 1)
            self._lock = "%s.lock" % args[0]
            while True:
                try:
                    self._flock = os.open(self._lock, os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL | os.O_WRONLY)
                    break
                except IOError:
                    time.sleep(interval)

            HDFStore.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """Exit and remove file lock."""

            HDFStore.__exit__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            os.close(self._flock)
            os.remove(self._lock)

    def write_hdf(f, key, df, complib):
        """Append pandas dataframe to hdf5.

        Args:
        f       -- File path
        key     -- Store key
        df      -- Pandas dataframe
        complib -- Compress lib 

        NOTE: We use maximum compression w/ zlib.
        """

        with SafeHDF5Store(f, complevel=9, complib=complib) as store:
            df.to_hdf(store, key, format='table', append=True)
```

Next I launch 100 jobs on a compute farm. They do some computation to generate a dataframe. Then they try to append their dataframe to this table. However, I'm getting the following error when trying to obtain the lock that I don't know how to resolve. Any suggestions?

```
File "/safehdf5.py", line 27, in __init__
    self._flock = os.open(self._lock, os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL | os.O_WRONLY)
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'osd.hdf5.lock'
```

It seems like the lock file already exists when another process tries creating it (while the process that holds the lock has not finished removing that file). I do have a *os.remove()* call in the *exit()* function to remove the file.

Comment: Try changing line 29 from `except IOError:` to `except (IOError, OSError):`.

Comment: Thanks. That worked.

Comment: Great. Made it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `__init___()` on line 29, you only wait to get the lock if there is an `IOError`:

```
while True:
    try:
        self._flock = os.open(self._lock, os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL | os.O_WRONLY)
        break
    except IOError:
        time.sleep(interval)
```

But, if the file already exisst, you get an `OSError`.
Therefore, except both types of errors and keep trying until you ar successful:

```
while True:
    try:
        self._flock = os.open(self._lock, os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL | os.O_WRONLY)
        break
    except (IOError, OSError):
        time.sleep(interval)
```