# Appending Published json Data to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, hdf5

I'm working on a solution to append json data from "ws.binaryws.com" to an hdf5 file. I have created the code below and it is working fine at least on getting the data as a single line item like the following output;

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
                    symbol        ask        bid      quote
date_time                                                   
2022-01-06 16:36:29  1HZ50V  550993.64  550933.64  550963.64 

                     symbol        ask        bid      quote
date_time                                                   
2022-01-06 16:36:30  1HZ50V  550965.93  550905.93  550935.93 

                     symbol        ask        bid      quote
date_time                                                   
2022-01-06 16:36:31  1HZ50V  550972.46  550912.46  550942.46 

                     symbol       ask       bid     quote
date_time                                                
2022-01-06 16:36:32  1HZ50V  551066.9  551006.9  551036.9
```

The output item of tick data is published by the second and I would like to append the tick data as it is published for later use.

**TARGET OUTPUT**

```
                    symbol        ask        bid      quote
date_time                                                   
2022-01-06 16:36:29  1HZ50V  550993.64  550933.64  550963.64
2022-01-06 16:36:30  1HZ50V  550965.93  550905.93  550935.93
2022-01-06 16:36:31  1HZ50V  550972.46  550912.46  550942.46
2022-01-06 16:36:32  1HZ50V  551066.90  551006.90  551036.90
```

**CODE**

```
import pandas as pd
import websocket
import json

from datetime import datetime

def on_open(ws):
    json_data = json.dumps({"ticks": "1HZ50V"})
    ws.send(json_data)


def on_message(ws, message):
    data = json.loads(message)
    data = data.get('tick')
    data_items = data.items()
    data_list = list(data_items)
    df_item = pd.DataFrame(data_list, columns=['', 'dictionary'])
    df_item = df_item.T
    headers = df_item.iloc[0]
    df_item = df_item[1:]
    df_item.columns = headers
    df_item['date_time'] = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df_item.date_time = pd.to_datetime(df_item.date_time, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df_item = df_item[['date_time', 'symbol', 'ask', 'bid', 'quote']]
    df_item.set_index('date_time', inplace=True)

    df_item.to_hdf('_prices.h5', key='HZ50V', append=True, mode='r+', format='t')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    apiUrl = "wss://ws.binaryws.com/websockets/v3?app_id="+app_id
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(apiUrl, on_message=on_message, on_open=on_open)
    ws.run_forever()
```

The code that is supposed to continually append the tick data to the hdf5 file does not seem to be working and I can't find out why it is failing.

**PROBLEMATIC CODE**

```
df_item.to_hdf('_prices.h5', key='HZ50V', append=True, mode='r+', format='t')
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution from [Obtaining a exclusive lock when writing to an HDF5 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231678/obtaining-a-exclusive-lock-when-writing-to-an-hdf5-file). It actual provided a more complete solution to my problem and is working as expected.